# Customize page numbering in plain TeX (not LaTeX)

Tags: page-numbering, plain-tex

I would like to change the page numbering from the default 1, 2, ... to the corresponding symbols in my native language. I have the fonts and typesetting ready and just want to replace the page numberings. How would I go about it ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you give some more clues? Are just the symbols different from Arabic digits, but the numbering system is decimal? Where are the symbols in the font?

Comment: how you typeset numbers depends on your native tongue: Roman is not Arabic. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Hi, I am the original poster. (just registered in TeX stackexchange. Cannot figure out how to edit my guest post) The number system is decimal. Following the lead given by Henri Menke below, I did the following which worked : \footline={\centerline{\od \folio}}. \od refers to the fonts I am using. Thanks everyone for the quick response.

Comment: you can ask for moderator help to merge accounts.  see [Help Center > My Account](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 8):

The page number is typeset by adding it to the token list `\footline`.  By default the page number is preprocessed by the macro `\folio`, which outputs a roman numeral if the page number is negative.  Below you can find the default definitions of plain TeX.

```
\footline={\hss\tenrm\folio\hss}
\def\folio{\ifnum\pageno<0 \romannumeral-\pageno \else\number\pageno \fi}
Text
\bye
```