# Suppress page number in TeX, NOT LaTeX

Tags: page-numbering, plain-tex

I am new to TeX family and I sincerely thank everyone for reading and replying this question.
I know in LaTeX this can be done by "\pagestyle{empty}", but this does not work on original TeX. What is the solution? Thanks again.

Comment: Try [`\def\folio{}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289392/customize-page-numbering-in-plain-tex-not-latex)

Comment: Plain TeX defines `\nopagenumbers` macro which does the same as `\pagestyle{empty}` in LaTeX.